# Why isn't the v-bind attribute working properly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm creating a simple To-Do List app using VueJS:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <br/>
      <div id="centre">
        <div id="myDIV" class="header">
          <h2 style="margin:5px">My To Do List</h2>
          <input type="text" id="myInput" v-model="text" v-on:keyup.enter="AddNote()" placeholder="Title...">
          <span v-on:click="AddNote()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
        </div>

        <ul id="myUL">
          <li v-on:click="ToggleClass(index)" v-for="(item, index) in array" v-bind:class="{ checked: isChecked[index] }">
            {{item}}
            <span class="close">×</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Notepad",

        data() {
          return {
            array: [],
            text: "",
            isChecked: []
          }
        },

        methods: {
          AddNote: function() {
            if(this.text!=="") {
              this.array.push(this.text);
              this.isChecked.push(false);
              this.text = "";
            }
          },

          ToggleClass(index) {
            console.log(index);
            this.isChecked[index]=!this.isChecked[index];
            console.log(this.isChecked);
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

However when I click on an item the v-bind attribute doesn't bind the class when I click on it. Instead it binds it when I type something in the text field above.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `isChecked` array is not reactive and vue cannot detect changes.
You have to trigger it, for example via `$set` or `splice`.

Read more about it here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

You can change your code like this:

```
ToggleClass(index) {
  console.log(index);
  this.isChecked.splice(index, 1, !this.isChecked[index])
  // or this.$set(this.isChecked, index, !this.isChecked[index])
  console.log(this.isChecked);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed the problem however now when I run the RemoveElement function it runs both the RemoveElement and the ToggleClass function. Is there a way for only one function to be run?

Comment: Nice to hear! Maybe you've wrapped the `ToggleClass` method around the `RemoveElement` method. Try this: `<li v-for="(item, index) in array" v-bind:class="{ checked: isChecked[index] }">
  <span v-on:click="ToggleClass(index)">{{item}}</span>
  <span v-on:click="RemoveElement" class="close">×</span>
</li>`.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow